# How a Galois Field is used to construct a Hamming Parity Matrix

Tags: information-theory

I'm trying to understand how Matlab is generating their Hamming parity matrix. The default according to the documentation is GF(2^m), where m=3.

#### Hamming(7, 4) parity matrix from Matlab

```
>> hammgen(3)

ans =

     1     0     0     1     0     1     1
     0     1     0     1     1     1     0
     0     0     1     0     1     1     1
```

#### Galois primitive polynomial output

```
>> gfprimdf(8)

ans =

     1     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1
```

How does the Galois field govern the arrangement of the Hamming parity matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/hammgen.html) say,

> The binary primitive polynomial used to produce the Hamming code is
>   the default primitive polynomial for $GF(2^m)$, represented by
>   `gfprimdf(m)`.

So, in our case we have $m=n-k=8-4=3$. Hence, we must compute the default primitive polynomial for $GF(2^3)$, by doing `gfprimdf(3)`, which gives $[ 1     1     0     1]$ or $p(X)=1+X+X^3$. Indeed, the cyclic $(7,4)$ code generated by this polynomial is a Hamming code. To understand the details you need to read about how [polynomial codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_code) work, specifically how the binary codewords can be mapped to polynomials in $GF(2)$ - this particular case (Hamming codes seen as cyclic codes) is treated in detail in [Lin & Costello, chapter 4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130426725)